# Saving un-do/re-do where there is no inverse action

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic, undo

Let's say I am in a spreadsheet application and do three actions:

1. (Open a new spreadsheet.)
2. Type "Hello" in cell A1.
3. Make cell A1 bold.
4. Type in "yellow" in cell A2.

In order to un-do all operations I could store something like:

```
UNDO_STACK = [
    {ActiveCell: 'A1', Text: ''},      # undo for "hello"
    {ActiveCell: 'A1', Bold: false},   # undo for bold
    {ActiveCell: 'A2', Text: ''},      # undo for "yellow"
]
```

Of course there can be tons more actions and the above data structure is quite simplified. However, my questions is how a complex action such as `"Replace 'e' with 'l'"` would work? I couldn't just save the 'action' because it is not exactly inversible, as much of the original data is lost. For something like a replace operation does an application like Excel or Google sheets need to save **every** replace operation that has been made? What if it's a very large file, such as a 500MB file in Excel, couldn't the undo operation itself take up ~10MB or more if storing the placement of every undo operation (for example, if half of the cell values are NULL and I want to replace NULL with '') ? How could the replace operation be saved in a memory-efficient way?

Comment: Your action 1. is also non-invertible, since whatever text was there before is lost. The solution is as you did for action 1.: store the additional information required to store the original state (in that case, the contents of cell A1 before it was changed). By the way, you need a stack of undo operations, not a queue.

Comment: @kaya3 -- thanks for the feedback. Regarding #1 -- let's assume it's a blank spreadsheet, the text before that was empty (so previous text = ''). Yes, a stack not a queue, sorry about that.

Comment: Yes, indeed, `''` is the text to restore for the first undo action because that was what was in A1 before the edit was made. A bulk search-and-replace also needs sufficient data to restore the old state. For a simple edit to one cell, the original text of that cell needs to be stored; for a bulk search-and-replace, a list of cells, indices and the deleted substrings would be sufficient. In principle you could compress it (e.g. gzip), but it's more likely you just store it as-is, and if it uses too much memory then you just don't store it, and that action can't be undone. 10MB is not a lot.

Comment: @kaya3 -- I see, thanks for the feedback. Would you want to put that in an answer with perhaps a 'general data structure' to store undo/redo operations on one or more cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most editing actions are non-invertible. For example, your first action of changing cell A1 to `"hello"` is non-invertible since it loses the previous text in that cell. The solution is as you wrote in your question: store the additional information required to restore the original state. In this case, the contents of cell A1 before it was changed were `""` (the empty string), so storing the empty string in the "undo" object allows the old state to be restored.

Likewise, a bulk search-and-replace operation is non-invertible, so it also needs sufficient data to restore the old state. A list of cells, indices and the deleted substrings would be sufficient. This object could contain quite a lot of data if the spreadsheet is large and many cells are affected; in principle you could compress it (e.g. using an algorithm like [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)), but I doubt many applications do this. It's more likely you would just store the "undo" object as is. Your example of needing 10MB of memory for a bulk edit on a large spreadsheet is not unrealistic, but also 10MB is not a lot of memory these days.

If an "undo" object would require too much memory, then you can always just choose not to store it, in which case that action (and any before it) can't be undone. In some circumstances (e.g. applying a transformation to the whole of a very large image), the information needed to undo the action is a complete copy of the original image, so you might instead get a warning that the operation will use a lot of memory and can't be undone. If you're implementing this, make sure to clear the whole undo stack when this happens.

Comment: thanks for this. Out of curiosity do you know how either Excel or GoogleSheets saves the state? Do they gzip or something else when saving large lists?

Comment: I don't know about specific applications, sorry!

Comment: got it. On a separate note, what about using a reserved character for the replace operation. For example changing `e` --> `l` actually does `e` --> `\x01l`, and so in the un-do operation we can do `\x01l` --> `e`. Though then we'd need to make sure that `\x01` character is reserved for the application. Would doing something like that (a bit of a hack) work in cases like this?

Comment: That could theoretically work if you had a different sentinel for each different find/replace operation, but it would add a lot of other complications, and you wouldn't want to do it with actual characters in the string (some specialised data structure would be needed, and it's not obvious it would take less memory to keep all the sentinels than it would to store indices in an "undo" object of where replacements occurred). A simpler solution might be to record the sequence of user actions and replay them from the saved version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is handled by creating a class or an object that contains all of the possible states. In your example, your properties for that cell would be `String` and `Bold (Bool).` There would be some function that detects a change to that particular object and then effectively saves it to a file or memory location that holds the data until it's needed. Interestingly different pieces of software use these states differently as you might expect. For example, Excel will store `undo` actions until the workbook becomes saved, but if Excel crashes, it will attempt to retain those actions when you recover the workbook. For reference, an excel sheet with approximately 80,000 cells will use about 20Mb of data if that data is only string values. It's essential to keep in mind when working with efficiency that there you could have a `Save` or a `Generate.`

**Save:** The save method would do precisely as you would expect. It's going to keep every change to your information in memory with whatever the designer is asking. If you want to undo an action, it merely reverts to the previous save, etc..

**Generate:** This one is a little different in that it's a known state change and can be calculated for the undo action. You can think of this type as a `computed property` to an object. Some of these generated undo actions are apparent, for example, a bold or un-bold action where there is a true/false. Other causes of a generated work might be more challenging to identify, such as a rotation of an image. Generating would be the most efficient way to handle the replacing of NULL in the most efficient manner. Your function would still need to save some value for your `)` but one character in memory is better than hundreds or thousands of characters in memory.

All in all, I think the more generatable undo actions you use, the more efficient it will be. Almost anything, barring static data, has an inverse operation that can be computed, thus saving memory. A copy/paste of a range of cells from cell A1 to A1:Z26 could be stored as a simple copy and paste using that exact information, Saving A1 and then merely copying that to A1: Z26 resulting in a dramatic performance increase over saving the entirety of A1:Z26 as an action.

I encourage you to check out this article, it contains great information that will help you understand better: https://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2008/12/19/undo-and-redo/

Comment: @xTwsiteDx -- thanks for this answer. Could you please clarify the following: `Generating would be the most efficient way to handle the replacing of NULL in the most efficient manner. Your function would still need to save some value for your ) but one character in memory is better than hundreds or thousands of characters in memory` ? For example, what is `)` ?

Comment: So "Null" is the lack of a value. In certain things such as JSON null is a string representation of having no value, granted attempting to parse it in some ways would result in an exception. It's known that "null" is the lack of a value so it's easy to store an undo action with null because it either has data or doesn't have data. Much like a `bool` is either true or false. You'd only need to know the current state to undo the action. Suppose you type into an empty cell, it was null before you started typing, so then you undo and the program knows that it was a null prior to so it replaces.